Qt Creator Tab settings
Starting with code:
template <size_t bits>
struct type_from_bits<bits, false, estd::internal::Range<(bits <= 8)> > :
    estd::type_identity<uint8_t>
{
};

adding a second base class, we get:
template <size_t bits>
struct type_from_bits<bits, false, estd::internal::Range<(bits <= 8)> > :
    estd::type_identity<uint8_t>,
                                                                          internal::type_from_bits_base<bits>
{
};

I encounter the same situation when calling functions, especially when passing in lambdas.  I already know about the ClangFormat area, but have had no luck there.  Please advise on both scenarios! Thank you!
